# ps options help, how to report a truncated list of processes sorted by desired columns

Tags: terminal, process, ps

Just discovered `ps`. Spent about 20 minutes reading through the `man ps`, testing out different options, but only found myself both more intrigued and deeply perplexed by the options. The ordinality and formatting of `ps [options]` escapes me, so I'm calling on the linux & terminal wizards for advice.

## What I'd like from `ps [options]`

The top 25 processes sorted by `%CPU`, then `%MEM` in the following columns:

`USER  TIME+    %CPU    %MEM    PID  CMD`

In the `--forest` ASCII tree style process hierarchy.

---

Essentially, a snapshot of `top`, with custom columns, with the `--forest` style process hierarchy.

**The closest examples to the output I'm looking for would be by referencing `top` and `ps -eH --forest`**

#### Example:

So basically this, but truncated to the top 25 processes by `%CPU` and `%MEM`, with the columns: `USER  TIME+    %CPU    %MEM    PID  CMD`

`...
 1023 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
 1056 tty7     00:01:55  \_ Xorg
 1215 ?        00:00:00  \_ lightdm
 1394 ?        00:00:00      \_ upstart
 1461 ?        00:00:00          \_ upstart-udev-br
 1464 ?        00:00:00          \_ dbus-daemon
 1529 ?        00:00:00          \_ upstart-dbus-br
 1533 ?        00:00:00          \_ upstart-file-br
 1535 ?        00:00:00          \_ upstart-dbus-br
 1538 ?        00:00:00          \_ at-spi-bus-laun
 1543 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ dbus-daemon
 1545 ?        00:00:01          \_ at-spi2-registr
 1555 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd
 1560 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd-fuse
 1599 ?        00:00:00          \_ gpg-agent
 1684 ?        00:00:00          \_ sh
 1695 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ xfce4-session
 1714 ?        00:00:08          |       \_ psensor
 1715 ?        00:00:16          |       \_ python2
 1824 ?        00:00:00          |       |   \_ gnome-pty-helpe
 1825 pts/1    00:00:00          |       |   \_ zsh
 8825 pts/1    00:00:00          |       |   |   \_ man
 8837 pts/1    00:00:00          |       |   |       \_ less
 4068 pts/2    00:00:00          |       |   \_ zsh
10783 pts/2    00:00:00          |       |   |   \_ ps
 6435 pts/7    00:00:00          |       |   \_ zsh
 1716 ?        00:00:00          |       \_ light-locker
 1718 ?        00:00:01          |       \_ nm-applet
 1725 ?        00:00:00          |       \_ polkit-gnome-au
 1726 ?        00:00:00          |       \_ update-notifier
 1738 ?        00:00:01          |       \_ applet.py
 1699 ?        00:00:00          \_ xfconfd
 1705 ?        00:00:11          \_ xfwm4
 1709 ?        00:00:01          \_ xfce4-panel
 1791 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ panel-1-whisker
 3837 ?        00:00:05          |   |   \_ go-for-it
 3922 ?        00:00:03          |   |   \_ xfce4-keyboard-
 5294 ?        00:01:29          |   |   \_ anki
 1800 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ xfce4-timer
 1807 ?        00:00:16          |   \_ panel-11-system
 1810 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ panel-4-systray
 1814 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ panel-5-power-m
 1821 ?        00:00:04          |   \_ panel-6-indicat
 1711 ?        00:00:05          \_ Thunar
 1713 ?        00:00:01          \_ xfdesktop
 1717 ?        00:00:00          \_ xfsettingsd
 1728 ?        00:00:00          \_ xfce4-volumed
 1732 ?        00:00:00          \_ dconf-service
 1748 ?        00:00:00          \_ xfce4-power-man
 1754 ?        00:00:00          \_ pulseaudio
 1802 ?        00:00:00          \_ gconfd-2
 1841 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfs-udisks2-vo
 1851 ?        00:00:00          \_ upstart
 1855 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ indicator-messa
 1856 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ indicator-sound
 1857 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ indicator-appli
 1853 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfs-mtp-volume
 1874 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfs-goa-volume
 1892 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfs-afc-volume
 1900 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfs-gphoto2-vo
 2214 ?        00:01:19          \_ chromium-browse
 2222 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ chromium-browse
 2224 ?        00:00:00          |   |   \_ chromium-browse
 2275 ?        00:00:03          |   |       \_ chromium-browse
 2290 ?        00:00:01          |   |       \_ chromium-browse
 2317 ?        00:00:00          |   |       \_ chromium-browse
 2334 ?        00:00:01          |   |       \_ chromium-browse
10709 ?        00:00:01          |   |       \_ chromium-browse
 2248 ?        00:00:55          |   \_ chromium-browse
 2262 ?        00:00:00          |       \_ chromium-browse
 3637 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd-metadata
 3641 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd-trash
 3848 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd-network
 3862 ?        00:00:00          \_ gvfsd-dnssd
10492 ?        00:00:01          \_ sublime_text
10502 ?        00:00:01              \_ plugin_host
 1050 ?        00:00:00 wpa_supplicant
...`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-o` option of `ps` allows a user-defined output format. We can also sort this output for a "top-25" view.  The imposition of a "forest" or process hierarchy option isn't possible when a `ps ... --sort ...` is chosen, though. Adding PPID to the output can expose hierarchical relationships.

Specifically in your case, we might do:

```
ps -e -ouser,time,cpu,vsz,ppid,pid,cmd --sort -time,user | head -26
```

This orders the output in order of descending time (largest value, first) and then by user within to give 25 "top" processes beneath a header line.